# InfoPath 2007: Submit data to SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that has custom code behind it that sends data to a SQL server DB.  Is there a way I can publish the form to SharePoint 2007 without needing admin approval?  If not, is there any alternative that will allow me to publish the form with custom code?  Last question, how do I acquire a certificate that allows the form to be used by multiple users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Any form with code needs to go through admin approval to be deployed in SharePoint. Because you want to submit to a DB, I don't believe you can use InfoPath Form Services anyways (unless you're submitting to a web service), so you may consider *installing* your form onto users desktops.

Look for a code signing certificate. We've had good experience with Verisign.